# PHPExcel expects date format d/m/y, but m/d/y entered. How to set PHPExcel Reader object to use custom date format for conversions

Tags: date, phpexcel, date-format

I need to read an excel spreadsheet with date format m/d/y into database. However, PHPExcel is outputting the wrong date because it thinks the date format is d/m/y.

How can I tell PHPExcel reader object to use the format m/d/y?

Comment: Is there anyone that can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For clarity if other people encounter this problem:

Spreadsheet contains date 02/04/2014

You/Client/Boss entered date to be: **m/d/y or February 4th, 2014**
PHPExcel sees it as: **d/m/y or April 2nd, 2014**

The solution is to avoid the situation altogether by using the correct date formatting when the spreadsheet is created or use general formatting instead.

Q) What do I do if my client provided the spreadsheet to me?
A) Search for an entire day for a solution until you come to the same conclusion as I did or you can save yourself time and ask the client to send you another spreadsheet with the correct formatting.

Answer (score 0):

If the date is simply a string in the excel file, then you can use the standard PHP functions for string to date conversion (either strtotime() or DateTime objects). If the date is stored as an Excel timestamp, then you can use the PHPExcel built-in functions (PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP() or PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject()) to convert from the Excel timestamp value to a PHP/Unix timestamp or DateTime object, and then use the standard PHP date functions or DateTime methods to format it however you wish.

Comment: I appreciate the response. However, it was not what I needed help with. The date format in the spreadsheet is m/d/y(02/04/2014) which is February 4th, 2014, but PHPExcel sees that date as d/m/y or April 2nd, 2014. That's the problem.

Comment: So what is the actual value in the spreadsheet? Is it a string? Is it an Excel timestamp? If the latter, what format mask is used? If there is a fault with date handling in PHPExcel, then (as the developer) I'd like to be able to fix it.... but I'm having real problems understanding what your problem is in the first place

Comment: Yes. It's an obscure situation. The value in the spreadsheet is date. The client entered the date value as m/d/y 02/04/2014, but excel converted it as d/m/y. Therefore, excel had converted the date value differently than what the client wanted. So instead of Feb 4th, excel saved it as Apr 2nd. If there was some way to ignore the date value and retrieve the string value displayed by Excel, that would be helpful in this situation.